# Sum of chi-square and sum of Gaussians

Tags: probability-distributions

I came up to a point where I needed to add a $\sum_{i=0}^{100}(X_i^2)$, and the $\sum_{i=0}^{100}(X_i)$ where $X_i$ are iid $N(0,1)$. Now, I know that the first term is a chi squared RV with n degrees (n being the number of Gaussian RVs), which can be further approximated to a $N(100,200)$. Similarly, the second term is also $N(0,100). 
Can I say something about the statistical relationship between the two? I feel that they are uncorrelated, but not independent. 
Is there a way to prove their uncorrelatedness,(in)dependence?

Lastly, would the sum still be a Gaussian, and can I write the expression for its variance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can simply develop the formula:
$$ \textstyle \text{cov}(\sum X_i^2,\sum X_i) = \sum \mathbb E(X_i^3) = 0.   $$
Also they are not independant as
$$ \textstyle E(\sum X_i^2 (\sum X_i)^2) \neq \mathbb E (\sum X_i^2) \mathbb E (\sum X_i)^2.$$
The sum is asymptotically Gaussian if you renormalize it (that is if you use that $(\sum X_i^2 - n)/\sqrt n \approx \mathcal N(0,1)$. You get from Cramer's theorem
$$ \textstyle \frac 1 {\sqrt n} (\sum (X_i^2 + X_i) -n ) \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal N( 0,3).  $$